Unable to migrate a WordPress site to local Docker environment after changing table prefixes
I am trying to migrate an online WordPress site (hosted at https://pace.ndrini.eu) to my local development environment using Docker. Despite updating the database table prefixes from pace_ to wp_, I can only access the WordPress login page at http://localhost:80. All other pages fail to load.
I suspect there might be an issue with the setup or configuration, but I cannot pinpoint the cause. I know the keys like AUTH_KEY, SECURE_AUTH_KEY, and similar ones in wp-config.php are unrelated since they mainly handle cookie security, not database communication.
Here is my docker-compose.yml file:
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    container_name: wordpress_db
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress_db
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress_password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: true
    volumes:
      - ./ndrinieu_pace_wp.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/database.sql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: wordpress_local
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress_user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress_password
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress_db
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content-backup_2024-12-25:/var/www/html/wp-content
volumes:
  db_data:

I have also updated the database dump (ndrinieu_pace_wp.sql) as follows:

Changed table prefixes from pace_ to wp_.
Updated siteurl and home in the wp_options table to http://localhost:80.

An excerpt of the modified database:
before
INSERT INTO `pace_options` (`option_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES
(2, 'siteurl', 'https://pace.ndrini.eu', 'on'),
(3, 'home', 'https://pace.ndrini.eu', 'on'),
``

after 
```sql
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES
(2, 'siteurl', 'http://localhost:80', 'on'),
(3, 'home', 'http://localhost:80', 'on');

Result
After the docker compose up command I can:

access the db in mysql (using dbeaver)
access the login page localhost:80/wp-login.php but access only admin pages /wp-admin/ no t public pages

Questions
My questions are:

Could the port mapping (80 to 80) in the wordpress service cause confusion or issues with the migration?
Then the error is The page isn’t redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. The problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
Yes for sure: I've tried also to map 8080 to 80, and works worst.

Are there other steps I should verify to debug this issue? (even if I force the debug, the logs are really poor or absent)


I have read posts about WordPress migrations, but many do not address scenarios involving Docker or are not answered (Migrate wordpress site to a docker container (local)) . I am open to suggestions and willing to try different configurations. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
I will probably try now to copy the original website AUTH_KEY value

changing in the db the values of 'siteurl' and 'home', both from 'http://localhost:80' to 'http://localhost' solved the loop error!

Since you have an existing database, the MYSQL_* environment variables aren't used. You need to use a username and password that's already defined in the database. It's documented here in the first paragraph under 'Environment Variables'.
